# Laravel Eloquent ORM whereHas with a foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, orm, eloquent

Here are the relationships:

A user has many skills, there is a join table user_skills. I need to search this table to return the profiles that have the particular skill. This is part of a bigger query that is being built, so that is why there is not a ->get() on here.

User Model

```
/**
 * A user may have many skills
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function skills()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Core\Platform\Models\UserSkill');
}
```

Below is the query that isn't doing what I need it to. I need it to return the users who have the particular skill, based on the ID being passed in the search (the $this->misc['search_skills'] value).

```
// Skills
$this->user = $this->user->whereHas('skills', function ($q)
{
     foreach ($this->misc['search_skills'] AS $skill)
     {           
          $q->orWhere('id', $skill);
     }
});
```

Any thoughts as to what I am doing wrong or how I could execute this in a different way?

Comment: i think you can use whereIn(,'skills' []) that would be my method of attack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$skills = $this->misc['search_skills']; // assuming this is an array
$this->user = $this->user->whereHas('skills', function ($q) use ($skills)
{
     $q->whereIn('id', $skills);
});
```

Any time you end up using orWhere multiple times on the same field, you should most likely be using whereIn.

Put the search skills into a variable ($skills), import that variable into your callback with `use`, then use whereIn.